# For Stream.generate(foo).parallel(), does foo have to be thread safe?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

I'm working with Java 8 Streams. I have a custom function, `foo()`, that yields an object, and I would like to parallel stream the objects it creates. I know `foo()` is not thread safe.

If I write `Stream.generate(foo).parallel()`, will `foo()` be called in an asynchronous manner? I.e. will objects be generated serially, and passed to parallel threads, or will multiple threads each generate objects as needed by calling `foo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While data races are not a guaranteed behavior, the following code

```
System.out.println(
    Stream.generate(new Supplier<Integer>() {
        int i; @Override public Integer get() { return i++; }
    }).parallel()
      .limit(10_000)
      .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or)
      .cardinality()
);
```

reproducibly prints numbers less than 10,000 in my environment, demonstrating that missing updates may indeed happen when the supplier is not thread safe.

Note that it is also possible that the supplier gets queried for more elements than needed for the result evaluation. E.g.

```
LongAdder adder = new LongAdder();
System.out.println(
    Stream.generate(new Supplier<Integer>() {
        int i; @Override public Integer get() { adder.increment(); return i++; }
    }).parallel()
      .limit(10_000)
      .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or)
      .cardinality()
);
System.out.println("queried "+adder+" times");
```

usually reports a number of queries greater than 10,000, while at the same time, the result reports less than 10,000 distinct elements due to the data race.

Making the supplier thread safe, changes the result to the correct number of 10,000 distinct elements, but the supplier may still got queried more than 10,000 times, hence, the result is not guaranteed to contain exactly the numbers from 0 to 9,999, as the stream created via `generate` is *unordered*, so any 10,000 distinct numbers from the supplier may be used.

Comment: I dont gwet the point in neither of the two examples. Well, the first sort of makes sense, a shared variable is updated from multiple threads, which implies that the Supplier must be thread safe, but the second is about `limit` perse, or that is just to enforce the first point?

Comment: @Eugene: even if your supplier is thread safe, you must not assume that it will be queried for the consumed elements only. That applies to all short-circuiting operations (and infinite streams require a short-circuiting operation to complete). `limit` is just an obvious example. And it’s easy to overlook that the stream returned by `generate` is *unordered*, so a lot of use cases that come into someone’s mind when seeing that method may turn out to be actually inappropriate when thinking again about it…

Comment: @Holger I appreciate the clarification above, that's a subtle and important point

Answer (score 5):

The supplier will be called from multiple threads as you can observe with a quick experiment:

```
Stream.generate(() -> Thread.currentThread().getId())
    .parallel()
    .limit(100000)
    .distinct()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Being called from multiple threads does not necessarily imply being called concurrently. Compare with, e.g. `forEachOrdered` whose action may be called from different threads, but not concurrently. So this test is not sufficient to determine whether the supplier must be thread safe. (Though, in this case, the supplier will indeed be evaluated concurrently and must be thread safe).